# How to export table and data without dbname

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

do any know how to export table and data without dbname? When I export all database and want to use in another database as import, there is an error, because it try to create database.

I need only tables and data.

Thank you
Stan

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Further down the list of export option list, you should see something called "Add `CREATE DATABASE` / `USE` statement". Unchecking that should have the desired effect.

[image: "Add database/use statement image]

Comment: This option is not there, here is the printscreen [link] https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20016998/phpmyadmin.png

Comment: @Stan which phpMyAdmin version are you using? This option was introduced in 4.0.5, which was over three years ago; I suggest upgrading.